# Replacing null value in Python with next available value by group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'value': [None,None,'A',None,'B',None]
})
```

I would like to replace missing values by the first next non missing value by group. The desired result is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'value': ['A','A','A','B','B',None]
})
```

Comment: Use `df['value'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].bfill()`

Comment: I have combined most possible combination, hope that will help you to choose your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['value'] = df.groupby(by=['group'])['value'].backfill()
print(df)

   group value
0      1     A
1      1     A
2      1     A
3      2     B
4      2     B
5      2   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way as @Erfan mention using backfill method [`DataFrameGroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html).

### Solution 1)

```
>>> df['value'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].bfill()
>>> df
   group value
0      1     A
1      1     A
2      1     A
3      2     B
4      2     B
5      2   NaN
```

### Solution 2)

[`DataFrameGroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) with `limit` parameter works perfectly as well here.
From the pandas Documentation which nicely briefs the [`Limit the amount of filling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) is worth to read. as per the doc `If we only want consecutive gaps filled up to a certain number of data points, we can use the limit keyword`.

```
>>> df['value'] = df.groupby(['group']).bfill(limit=2)
# >>> df['value'] = df.groupby('group').bfill(limit=2)
>>> df
   group value
0      1     A
1      1     A
2      1     A
3      2     B
4      2     B
5      2   NaN
```

### Solution 3)

With `groupby()` we can also combine `fillna()` with `bfill()` along with limit parameter.

```
>>> df.groupby('group').fillna(method='bfill',limit=2)
  value
0     A
1     A
2     A
3     B
4     B
5  None
```

### Solution 4)

Other way around using [`DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) function to fill the `value` column after group by with [`DataFrameGroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html).

```
>>> df['value'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].transform(lambda v: v.bfill())
>>> df
   group value
0      1     A
1      1     A
2      1     A
3      2     B
4      2     B
5      2  None
```

### Solution 5)

You can use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to add the `group` column to the index, making it unique, and do a simple `bfill()` via `groupby()`, then you can use reset index to its original state.

```
>>> df.set_index('group', append=True).groupby(level=1).bfill().reset_index(level=1)
   group value
0      1     A
1      1     A
2      1     A
3      2     B
4      2     B
5      2   NaN
```

### Solution 6)

In case strictly not going for `groupby()` then below would be the easiest ..

```
>>> df['value'] = df['value'].bfill()
>>> df
   group value
0      1     A
1      1     A
2      1     A
3      2     B
4      2     B
5      2  None
```

Comment: Solutions 2 & 3 seem overly complex and superfluous.

Comment: @PaulH, thanks for the comments, its more time intensive but just an approach   I will drop that to level down on its numbering :-)

Comment: Chronology has been changed in order to pick them easily understandable first.